# Firestore consulta simple

Tags: android, sql, google-cloud-firestore

De la pagina de Firestore, para hacer consultas simples:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?hl=es

Después de hacer la consulta y si no existe el resultado, no me arroja el "else", ¿por qué?

```
        .whereEqualTo("capital", true)
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré después de estar probando varios métodos y herramientas una solución.

Intrepreto que realiza la busqueda, pero por tiempo no valida correctamente, asi que si no encuentra el valor al finalizar el ciclo for, ahi le pongo el detalle para la solucion

```
    .whereEqualTo("capital", true)
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    texview.setText(document.getId().toString());
                }
                if(texview.getText.toString.equals(""){
                    texview.setText("Sin resultados");
                }
            } 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Porque el `else` es para un error. Si no existe el resultado pero la consulta se hizo correctamente entonces la función `isSuccessful()` devuelve verdadero.

Prueba por ejemplo quitando los permisos de lectura y eso te dará un error que aparecerá en el `else`.

Answer (score 0):

prueba de esta manera:

```
.whereEqualTo("capital" != true)
```

o

```
.whereEqualTo("capital" == true)
```

Comment: La pregunta es "porque no me arroja el "else"?".

Comment: el problema, es si no encuentra la informacion no me arroja el "else"